# Alternative expression for "xyz Nazi"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, politeness

I'm not a native English speaker, but I do understand and personally appreciate the use of the term "xyz Nazi" to say that someone is a bit dogmatic about their point of view, without necessarily offending them. A related question here on SE is:

[Is "grammar nazi" politically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21935/15834)

But most often, my writing doesn't address only English speakers, but also others. Being a native German speaker (although not from Germany), I'm a bit more sensitive to how this might be received with my every day audience.

What would be an equivalent term with a similar semantics (funny, slightly reproachful, but not really offensive)?

Comment: The *Grammar Police* is a mass noun that's used sometimes slightly reproachfully...

Comment: a simple replacement is "Fanatic".  Grammar Fanatic, Soup Fanatic, Design Fanatic, etc.

Comment: Let's not be beastly to the Nazis.

Comment: @JoeBlow: How I understand it, *"xyz Fanatic"* is someone who's enthusiast about, but a *"xyz Nazi"* would be someone who insists on things being done this or that way...

Comment: Anyone who makes such flippant use of the word 'Nazi' should I suggest, read Edward Russell's *The Scourge of the Swastika'. Lord Russell was a British war-crimes prosecutor at Nuremberg. Prepare for a ghastly and terrifying experience.

Comment: @WS2: Precisely. While it may sound funny to some people in very informal contexts, it's certainly a no-go in most situations

Comment: Hi Lukas *"How I understand it, "xyz Fanatic" is someone who's enthusiast about, but a "xyz Nazi" would be someone who insists on things being done this or that way"* (1) you can't put that fine a point on it, really - it's a humorous phrase. (2) all I can say is, I'm pretty sure there's no better substitute

Comment: @WS2 - the thing is, Mel Brooks http://youtu.be/kHmYIo7bcUw he's jewish right, points out it's probably best to make fun of 'em.  It's tricky too: numerically Stalin deaded more humans than Hitler, and Mao deaded more humans than Stalin. But Stalin is discussed with relative normalcy and Mao is "trendy, dude".  So, it's tough.  Note too that Seinfeld is Jewish right? (coined the "xyz nazi" term)

Comment: "We find the defendants incredibly guilty"  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow: I really like the *"xyz Police"*, and *"Stickler of xyz"* is also a good substitute, just like *"xyz zealot"* (as suggested by other answers)

Comment: I definitely would not use "Police".  In that phrase, you use "evil" things like "nazi" "kgb" etc.  It's just plain rude to use "police"!  Plus it's a **different meaning**.   there's **another distinctly different** phrase with police:  so, "clean underwear police!", a mom who is always CHECKING for clean underwear. it's a different thing

Comment: As noted below, "Nazi" carries a connotation of being oppressive and tyrannical.  (There's another word for it that doesn't come to mind at the moment.)  Many of the suggestions do not carry this connotation, so one would need to judge whether the connotation is important or not.

Comment: I think "Grammar Justice Worker" communicates the same idea but frames it in a more positive, accepting way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Making an assumption here about your allusion, that this is a good idea rather assumes that your target audience sees Social Justice Warriors as positive and accepting; certainly, this is far from the typical experience.

Comment: I prefer to be called a "Knight of Shining Grammar"

Comment: @RichardVenable - When people hear my grammar I often hear them mutter "good knight!"

Comment: How about "Don't get so P-ist"?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As @Araucaria says in the comments, **Grammar Police** is an excellent alternative that conveys the fascistic tendencies of a police state without the genocidal implications.

Comment: I agree. *"Police"* might really be the best match removing all negative connotation that *"Nazi"* has

Comment: Unless you're - oh - a policeman or policewoman? And you find jokes about pigs, cops, police etc offensive to your family.

Comment: @JoeBlow the implication is that the Grammar Police are presiding over a frivolous area, not that Police are by nature frivolous and unnecessary.

Comment: Sure dude - you'd say it to your grandpa who's a Sheriff right?  There's never ANY danger of offending anyone these days!  :)

Comment: @mskfisher "Let's eat grandma." vs. "Let's eat, grandma." - Punctuation (defined by grammar) saves lives, as is thus not "frivolous and unnecessary".

Comment: This is the commonly used phrase when talking about someone who nitpicks grammar.  There are others though, such as "rule lawyers" who nitpick rules in board games.  I've never heard of a "grammar lawyer" though "rule police" might be understood.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Totally related: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Eats-Shoots-Leaves-Lynne-Truss/dp/0007329067

Comment: @JoeBlow: If "grandpa who's a Sheriff" isn't aware that there's a risk for police to be frivolous, and that this is a real problem for many people, he probably needs to be offended.

Comment: of course, "political correctness" varies.  but here's no connection to "frivolous" here.  "nazis" "kgb" etc were, eg., genocidists, torturers, etc.  (little connection to "frivolous".)  As it ses above ........ "I (suggest to) definitely would not use "Police".  In that phrase, you use "evil" things like "nazi" "kgb" etc.  It's just plain rude to use "police" (putting them in that grouping)!  Plus it's a different meaning.   there's another distinctly different phrase re police:  so, "clean underwear police!", a mom who is always CHECKING for clean underwear. it's a different thing"

Comment: There's also the "police state" which the KGB, etc. refers to.

Comment: I don't know *anybody* who would be offended by the use of a phrase like "grammar police" here in the US. I can't even imagine how one could consider it offensive to members of the police. It is a literal definition of what they're doing, which is *policing grammar*.

Comment: @mskfisher: By that logic, "Grammar Nazi" only suggests that the target is the ruling party in Germany in the 1930s, not that they necessarily partake in all those nastinesses that are more popularly associated with the Nazi party nowadays. so no!

Comment: Also related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9_kahA_wQo

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's a difference between using a word with very negative connotations in a metaphor and using a more neutral word this way. Do you think physicians are bothered by metaphors using the word "doctor"?

Comment: @ChrisHayes I must agree.  I live here in the USA, and the word Police by itself is not offensive.  "Pigs", "Po Po", etc. are all reserved for offensive connotations of Police, but Police itself is pretty benign.  Besides, there is a great comedy precedent for "Grammar Police" in the parallel jokes about "Fashion Police".

Answer (score 43):

[Pedant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedant) comes to mind

> A pedant is a person who is excessively concerned with formalism, accuracy & precision, or who makes an ostentatious and arrogant show of learning.
>   <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: Yes, that's probably the most accurate term. I wonder though, if it is perceived more negative than "xyz Nazi"...?

Comment: "Pedant" is incredibly not colloquial, dudes! Also, it doesn't, really, work as a replacement .. Soup Pedant, Grammar Pedant,  Design Pedant, etc.

Comment: What would be Soup Nazi?

Comment: @jnovacho: [*"No soup for you!"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svSGKJFSl-8), obviously. ;-)

Comment: @JoeBlow Also, it doesn't *really* work as a replacement ... -- A grammar pedant

Comment: Hi @jnovacho ... "Soup Nazi" is a phrase from a well-known TV show. Just google for explanation.  It's a person who is "fanatical about soup"

Comment: @JoeBlow: pedant is colloquially used, it is up to us not to let human discourse regress into Seinfeldisms. *"Don't be pedantic about grammar"* works fine.

Comment: Hey smci.  I encourage use of pedant; it does not really work in the "xyz Pedant" formula. Regarding devolving to Seinfeldisms, I'm still angry nobody knows how to use apocryphal correctly.

Comment: @LukasEder I think I can safely say that the only term in English that even comes close to the negative associations with the word "Nazi" is "terrorist."

Comment: @JoeBlow Is there a Seinfeld episode that makes significant use of the word "apocryphal"?

Comment: Hey @Kyle, I used the phrase "devolving to Seinfeldisms" following smci's usage; ie generally "people talk crap these days and don't have good English".  On that, actually I guess Seinfeld and (of course, obviously) GG Caron are perhaps two of the more literate, bon-mot filled nexii on US TV. So it's perhaps a bad rap to use "Seinfeldisms" to indicate "the appalling collapse in literacy."

Comment: @JoeBlow Ah, got it. I thought there was some particular "Seinfeldian" usage of "apocryphal."

Answer (score 33):

[*Fascist*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascist) (in its informal sense of someone who believes in authoritarian, dictatorial control) is a slightly less-charged term, although it's still fairly charged. [Merriam-Webster]

[*Stickler*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stickler) (*"a person who insists on something unyieldingly"*) is a good uncharged term that still carries a solid meaning. Being uncharged, it lacks the ... impact ... of the other terms, but this is ever the problem: You want impact, but without offending. [dictionary.reference.com]

Comment: *"stickler - a person who insists on something unyieldingly"*. That would be it, I guess. Fascist ist technically correct, but would risk making it more offensive, I guess

Comment: @LukasEder: Yeah, I'd probably go with stickler if I were at all worried someone would take fascist wrong. I'd *never* use Nazi. I did that once on CompuServe in ~1994 (calling myself a "comment nazi" [because I feel strongly about commenting source code in programming]), and got a very polite reply from a German saying "I'm not sure what you meant to convey, but I can assure you that here in Germany, the word has no positive connotations." 20 years later, I still remember that phrase exactly.

Comment: Crowder - that guy was soo German  :)  But seriously, "Stickler" is a great suggestion.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder reminds me of sitting next to a christian in England and muttering *Jesus H. Christ* and being told that "Jesus is my friend, please do not take his name in vain* - arrgh

Comment: Hey what about Grammar Stasi ?

Comment: I think Fascist still has strong connotations. I'd really avoid using it!!!

Comment: @JoeBlow Don't ever use Stasi to someone who hails from former East-Germany. Most will consider it even worse than Nazi.

Comment: Hey Tonny - right, that's why I made the example.

Comment: The term, an "xyz fascist", is very common in the UK, with those of us that grew up watching "The Young Ones" in the 80's. No offence would be taken amongst that generation. In other generations and cultures offence may be taken. Like all language/slang, it is a generational/cultural thing.

Answer (score 20):

A word with an interesting history that conveys a similar meaning is *[Zealot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zealot)*. Merriam-Webster tells of the Jewish origins of the word whose current definition is:

> a person who has very strong feelings about something (such as religion or politics) and who wants other people to have those feelings

Comment: Ah, but Zealots were (ostensibly) "freedom fighters" -- doesn't carry the connotation of being oppressive.

Comment: @HotLicks Ask the opposing side if they might feel if they were being oppressed.

Comment: But the Zealots, to my knowledge, never succeeded in "oppressing" anyone.  (Never succeeded in much of anything, in fact.)

Comment: @HotLicks it appears your comment was the only one to use oppress* on this topic. How may I incorporate your comment as whether my answer complies with the posted question?

Comment: For this kind of question there is no "right" or "wrong" answer.  Any answer that is even halfway on topic adds to the discussion and helps others understand the various subtleties of English words.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not looking to make this right or wrong. I'm trying to understand how your comment regarding oppression is relevant to the question or my comment.

Comment: I'm speaking of connotations here.  "Nazi" (to most in the US, at least) has a connotation of oppression/coercion that "Zealot" does not.

Comment: @HotLicks, while Zealot doesn't carry the same kind of negative connotation as Nazi does, it certainly doesn't carry any _positive_ connotations in my mind.

Comment: So you never do anything with great zeal?

Answer (score 16):

Go with "***[freak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/freak)***".

> A person who is obsessed with a particular activity or interest

Examples:

> Grammar-freak, gym-freak, movie-freak.

"Nerd" would be another option.  Grammar-nerd; although this implies more of an academic or otherwise studious interest.

Comment: Interesting, it might work in some occasions. But an "xyz Nazi" is someone who insists in being right, whereas an "xyz freak" just has heavy interest

Comment: Fair point.  How about something like "Grammar-overlord" or "grammar-dictator".  Grammar police is probably your best bet.

Comment: Good suggestions. I like "overlord" :-)

Comment: "freak" outstanding idea

Comment: *freak* has, among other meanings, sexual connotations in US English

Comment: @smci What *doesn't*? :p (That said, I agree, freak/nerd/etc. only imply that you want to do something correctly *yourself*, while the "nazi" idiom implies that you also want to force everyone else to do that thing according to your definition of correctness.)

Comment: I'm saying *freak* is nearly as bad as *Nazi* in connotations, whereas perfectly viable alternative words exist; let us use them already. Let us keep *pedantic* in use.

Comment: "Freak" nearly as bad as "Nazi"?  I know which I'd prefer to be labeled.  Also, in British English, "freak" is rarely used with sexual connotations.

Answer (score 4):

Two archaic words which I found in *The Chambers Dictionary*, but which are pretty much self-explanatory

- **a gerund-grinder** = *a pedantic teacher*
- **a grammaticaster** = *a piddling grammarian*

[image]

Source: *A complete dictionary of the English language*
 By Thomas Sheridan (1797)

Comment: Oh, I just encountered this word in Johnson's dictionary, and cross referenced it against a few others. Actually, while the definition is self-explanatory, I do think the answer could benefit from a little more explanation regarding the etymological form of grammaticaster. Specifically, information regarding the [-aster](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/-aster) suffix shown in the Century Dictionary might make this more generally applicable as an alternative to XYZ nazi, rather than just a replacement for the general example given. Would you mind if I made an edit?

Comment: @Tonepoet thanks this is an answer that was posted over 2 years ago on a question that was asked a year earlier, I'm fine with it. It's an archaic term which I bumped into by chance, and although the -astor suffix information is interesting (a Latin pejorative diminutive) it won't make this suggestion any more relevant. Thanks anyway for the offer.

Answer (score 3):

Just FTR, I guess "perfectionist" is the completely straightforward, straight, non-offensive, alternate that is, precisely, the "exact" meaning Lukas E. is after.

> Grammar Perfectionist
>
> Soup Perfectionist

etc.

IMO "stickler" is the best "fun" way to say it.  Again, that precisely implies "spends time correcting mistakes, is offended by slight errors."

---

Also: it occurs to me it's somewhat common to use other alternate Hated Totalitarian Organisations, something like ...

> "What are you, the grammar stasi?"
>
> "What are you, the grammar FBI?"  (/CIA /NSA /NRO etc)
>
> "What are you, the grammar KGB?"

---

One more random approach seen in the wild ... "___ patrol".  So, "What are you, the grammar patrol?"

Comment: Don't ever use Stasi to someone who hails from former East-Germany. Most will consider it even worse than Nazi.

Answer (score 3):

He **thinks he's the last word** on grammar.

He **runs a tight ship** where grammar is concerned.

He **operates a zero-tolerance regime** on grammar.

He **takes no prisoners** where grammar is concerned.

He **brooks no dissent** on grammar.

Comment: Very nice! I only wish I had more than one vote to give ;O) `Martinet` is another fun word for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't be so *Dogmatic*

as well as:

- *Pedant* /*Pedantic* (*"Don't be pedantic about grammar"*)
- *Stickler* *(*"Don't be such a stickler about grammar"*)*

Answer (score 1):

> He's OCD about...

Obsessive compulsive disorder, similar sort of tendency to a "xyz Nazi".

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I feel it's worth noting that the word "fiend" probably conveys the meaning you're looking for and is sometimes used like this.

It can [refer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiend) to a fanatic or to someone who is evil.  Which is pretty much the same as the meaning of "Nazi" in "xyz Nazi".  Plus, unless your readers are literal demons, I don't think you're likely to offend anyone with it.

One thing to watch out for though, is that the tone/context can probably inadvertently confer a mischievous connotation to the word "fiend" (e.g. "you're a grammar *fiend*," so-and-so said as he cackled maniacally), whereas I doubt you would be able to convey mischievousness with the word "Nazi", even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

**Martinet** or **overseer** are quite overbearing and repressive terms. Both are nouns as requested. For something with even more of a snarl, consider "grammar hegemon" in the style of *Ender's Game*. "Hegemon" was the title used for Ender's older brother, Peter, at the very end of the novel.

*
 For an overbearing female enforcer, perhaps, "grammar dominatrix" although that may have inseparably strong connotations of sexuality.

Answer (score 1):

Amusingly, Wikipedia's entry for "[Grammar Nazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_Nazi)" redirects to "Linguistic prescription," so you could also use "XYZ prescriptivist":

> A: No, it's different *from*.
>   B: Thanks, Mr. Grammar Prescriptivist.

Comment: Ah, the old "prescriptivist" vs "[descriptivist](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat)" debate.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***grammar bluenose***?

> **bluenose**
>
> A puritanical person: *Bluenoses demand restraint against the porn and violence that are the staple of popular culture* (Charles Krauthammer). [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bluenose)
>
> *Well, the grammar bluenoses will tell you that, except in extraordinary circumstances, only people should show ownership with a 's possessive construction, in which case the phrase would be "a table showing the maturity date of each category of debt."*
>
> *Actually, in this case, I would side with the bluenoses.* [StraightDope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-198383.html)
>
> *I'm only crabby sometimes, and certainly no language bluenose.* [The Chronicle of Higher Education](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2011/09/18/but-vs-though-a-distinction-that-matters/)

Answer (score 0):

**Bloody-minded**--describes someone who makes difficulties for other people by opposing their actions or ideas for no good reason. (the Free Dictionary)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that term. It seems to have a very negative alternative meaning in British English, though: [*"deliberately obstructive and unhelpful"*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bloody-minded)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't see this in the same context at all.

Comment: This is an adjective.   The question is looking for a noun.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: that's a chicken-and-egg. Before '-- nazi', there were already tons of viable alternatives, and they were mostly adjectival (e.g. *'He is dogmatic about X'* rather than *'He is a dogmatist'*)

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave my other answer because I agree that it implies interest rather than authority.

I'll go with **Grammar Overlord**.

Answer (score 0):

Agree about eschewing "Nazi." 
I prefer "grammar boffin." It seems to me it's high time to reverse the pernicious juggernaut of pejoratives aimed at educated people.

Answer (score -1):

Since this term was used in a Tatort (sunday evening tv show in Germany) episode this year, it is now perfectly fine to use this term in Germany!

Comment: Just because the phrase is used in a German-speaking crime drama does not make it an acceptable phrase for polite company. (Of course, the phrase is a nonissue in the US.)

Comment: It is not a German-speaking crime drama, it is THE German-speaking crime drama!

Answer (score -1):

I prefer **Grammar / xyz fundamentalist**.

Answer (score -3):

I just saw it in the supermarket recently, a much-belated pc-brutalized product tie-in for *Seinfeld's* "The Soup Nazi". The child-safe version is ...

> The Soup Man

Comment: It's actually "Soup Man":
http://originalsoupman.com/

Comment: @mskfisher Interesting that the [rules for the press](http://originalsoupman.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/rules_press.gif) prohibit the “‘N’ word”.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Often, the "N" word refers to a different n word. Given the URL, I think you are correct, that it is the Nazi n word.